# Passing user defined argument to RPM is possible while installing?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

Passing User defined argument to RPM is possible while installing?.

for example:

```
~>rpm -i sample.rpm -license_path=/path/
```

or

```
~>rpm -i -license_path=/path/ sample.rpm
```

or

```
~>rpm -i -somearg sample.rpm
```

-Sakthi

Comment: @malenkiy_scot - Thanks for editing and made question clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RPMs aren't meant to take user defined arguments.

See [RPM - Install time parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258647/rpm-install-time-parameters)

Another similar question is at https://superuser.com/questions/408852/is-it-possible-to-get-users-input-during-installation-of-rpm

One workaround is to have the rpm's postinstall script ask for input from stdin, in which case you can pass in the answers by redirecting stdio from a file or here document.

```
>rpm -i sample.rpm <<__NOT_RECOMMENDED__
somearg
__NOT_RECOMMENDED__
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a [relocatable RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-reloc.html).

In the preamble of your `.spec` file, put the prefix of the file path that can be relocated. 
For example, if the full path to your file is

```
/base/path/to/my/file
```

then `/base` can be changed during RPM installation but `/path/to/my/file` will remain the same.

Here's what you put in your `.spec` file:

```sh
#Preamble: Summary, Name, etc.
Prefix: /base
```

Ensure that you mention this prefix while listing all relocatable files in the `%install` and `%files` sections in the `.spec` file. There are conditions where a relocatable RPM may not work, so check out [these things to consider](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-reloc-wrinkles.html) as well.

```sh
%files
%{prefix}/path/to/my/file
```

Now when you install the RPM, you can specify a different prefix.

```sh
rpm -i sample.rpm  --prefix /tmp
```

This will install the file in `/tmp/path/to/my/file`.