# How would I make "read" command work in RPM spec file?

Tags: redhat, rpm, specifications, rpmbuild

I wrote a SPEC file to build RPM package. I need to let end user to determine the value of an variable in the `%pre` section. So I use "read  < my_variable >" command in the `%pre` section. But, when installing, the "read" command seems ignored by system, because the system didn't wait for me to enter the value. Why? and Is there any good method to do the above thing?

Comment: No. Don't do this. RPMs really need to be installable in an unattended fashion (or you will greatly annoy many sysadmins). Find some other way to do what you want. (Even requiring a file to exist on disk with the correct configuration before installation would work though it is a bit ugly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than embed the `read` within your package, RPM has a conditional mechanism which can be used via command-line parameters.  Most usage of conditionals in RPMs tests constants defined in the system's RPM macros or making simple filesystem checks.  You should investigate those first, because it allows your package to install without help from the person doing the install.

Here are some useful pages discussing RPM conditionals:

- [Passing conditional parameters into a rpm build](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/conditionalbuilds.html) (rpm.org)
- [PackagerDocs/ConditionalBuilds](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/ConditionalBuilds) (rpm.org)
- [Conditionals](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-conditionals.html) (Maximum RPM: Taking the Red Hat Package Manager to the Limit)
- [openSUSE:RPM conditional builds](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:RPM_conditional_builds)

As one can see from the suggested reading, these are *build-time* rather than *install-time* features.  You cannot make an "interactive" RPM install.  To read more about that, see these pages:

- [Is it possible to get user's input during installation of rpm?](https://superuser.com/questions/408852/is-it-possible-to-get-users-input-during-installation-of-rpm)
- [RPM - Install time parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258647/rpm-install-time-parameters)

The latter is clear that this is intentional on the part of the developers.  As an aside, one response mentions the `--relocate` option, implying that this solves the problem.  However, it is actually different.  Read more about *that* here:

- [Relocatable packages](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/relocatable.html)
- [Chapter 15. Making a Relocatable Package](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-reloc.html) (Maximum RPM)

Comment: Note: These are all at **build time** and not install time.